# Does someone know this function?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am interested in the function $F(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x/k}}{k^{d/2}}$ where $d$ is an integer bigger than $3$.
Of course this is a $C^{\infty}$ function. It is decreasing and convex. Thus it seems to be a nice function!

My question is the following one. Does someone know how to get a nice expression for this function or is it a "well-known" function? I tried many things like finding an differntial equation or doing a Taylor expansion of the exponential function but it was not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Expand the exponential in a Taylor series and interchange the summations.  You get
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\exp{(-x/k)}}{k^s} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-x)^m}{m!} \zeta(s+m).$$  I want to think the latter series has been studied asymptotically as $x \to \infty,$ but I don't have access to my math papers at the time.